# Can I get a real world scenario of using local functions inside a method in C# 7.0.?

Tags: c#-7.0

I have read by referring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions but I am not able to understand the value of this feature newly added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "real time", but, for me, the most valuable is not polluting the list of members of a type with a method that is only used by another one.

You can also close over local variables, but that can lead to unwanted allocations and change the lifetime of objects. That's why C# 8.0 introduces static local functions.